# why pkill is not killing the command python blink_led.py&

Tags: bash, pkill

I run a command :

```
python blink_led.py &
```

Then I try to kill it with `pkill`

```
pkill blink_led.py
```

But it doesn't work

Even after checking [man pag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)e, I don't understand how pkill works

Comment: Use the `-f` option to match the entire command line. Without that, it just matches the program name, which is just `python`.

Comment: you rock! Thanks for the help, and sorry it is not on the SO scope, will remember it for next time!